# webdriver issue on IE

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

here is the sample code that is not working on IE. its working on FF . Other websites are working without any issues.  Please help

```
driver.get("https://etrade.com");
if (driver.getTitle().contains("Certificate Error")) {
    driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
}
driver.findElement(By.id("user-id")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("user-id")).sendKeys("skbiUser ID");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("skb");
driver.findElement(By.id("log-on-submit")).click()
```

I am using selenium 2.35, IE9 , win7. Can any one check if they can make these code work on their machines.

Comment: Well what doesn't work? What errors? What happens? What is supposed to happen? What does FF do differently to IE?

Answer (score 0):

I got an error indicating password field was not visible in IE. Webdriver would not sendKeys to hidden (not visible) field. I used the following python code to set password:

```
script = 'document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("value","myPassword")'
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Password field was updated with 'myPassword', and I was able to logon.

I hope this will help you.